# overload for '\*=' that accepts CGFloat

Tags: swift

I'm studying Swift and trying to make some very simple application. I met a thing that I can't understand:

When I write

```
var point = CGPoint(x: 0.6, y: 0.6)
let size = CGSize(width: 15, height: 25)
point.x *= size.width
point.y *= size.height
```

compiler thinks that's all right.
But if I write the same in the extension

```
extension CGPoint {
    func scale(bySize size: CGSize) {
        self.x *= size.width
        self.y *= size.height
    }
}
```

I have an error *Could not find an overload for '*=' that accepts the supplied arguments* on each line in the function.

Could anybody explain what does it mean and what the difference?

point and size are the same in both cases, why in first case the *= operator exists but in the second one it does not?

Answer (score 3):

```
mutating func scale(bySize size: CGSize) {
    self.x = self.x * size.width
    self.y *= size.height
}
```

you have to state that the function want to mutate the state of a "by value" struct.

> „Structures and enumerations are value types. ...

if you need to modify the properties of your structure or enumeration within a particular method, you can opt in to mutating behavior for that method. ...“

Auszug aus: Apple Inc. „The Swift Programming Language.“ iBooks. https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewBook?id=881256329

Comment: This is also explained here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Methods.html - Modifying Value Types from Within Instance Methods

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the keyword `mutating` into your implementation:

```
extension CGPoint {
    mutating func scale(bySize size: CGSize) {
        self.x *= size.width
        self.y *= size.height
    }
}
```

You can find this in the [docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-XID_199):

> Instance methods added with an extension can also modify (or mutate)
>   the instance itself. Structure and enumeration methods that modify
>   self or its properties must mark the instance method as **mutating**, just
>   like mutating methods from an original implementation.

Then they provide this example:

```
extension Int {
    mutating func square() {
        self = self * self
    }
}
var someInt = 3
someInt.square()
// someInt is now 9
```